Can descriptive statistics of three ordered groups be converted into a correlation?
I know that a one-way ANOVA with two groups can be converted into a Standardized Mean Difference (SMD), that can, in turn, be converted into a Pearson correlation. Anyway, with two group means and standard deviations (SDs), one could perform a t-test, that can in turn be into a converted into a SMD (I am always assuming we know both sample sizes).
Can this conversion be performed when we have three groups? Moreover, these groups are ordinal ("low", "medium" and "high").
Of course, if I had the data, I would do something different (I would use continuous data also for the grouped variable, or the Kendall's tau), but unfortunately, I only have the three group means, SDs, and sizes.
I know I could calculate the three correlations separately, or lump two groups or ignore one in order to return to the two-group setting.
However, is there any way to get a sensible correlation coefficient by using all the available information? Can the information from the F-statistics (with 2 numerator degrees of freedom) and/or the variance "between" and "within groups" be used somehow?
